# Liquibase: Unable to recognizing data type CLOB

Tags: liquibase

I m used Liquibase to reverse engineer Microsoft MYSQL database where I see changeset for CLOB datatype generated as VARCHAR

When I execute the changeset to new environment, as expected Column Profile is created as VARCHAR instead of CLOB.

Is this a known issue or any workaround is provided from API.

Liquibase version: 3.6.2

Comment: This happens with quite a few types. You have to change them manually

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. You can use `updatesql` to generate a SQL file where you can manually change the data type from VARCHAR to CLOB.
2. You can use `<SQL>` tags in your changelog file to let liquibase generate it as you want, for example:

   ```
   <sql>
       CREATE TABLE (ID NUMBER, QUERY CLOB);
   </sql>
   ```

   In this case you would have to take care of the rollback by yourself.